# Django REST API の返送で、json.dumps関数で生成した文字列が意図通りにならない

Tags: python3, json, django-rest-framework

rest_frameworkで、データベースに連携しない形で、任意のJSONレスポンスを返しますが、json.dumps関数によるインデントを含めると、正しく表示できません。

リクエスト

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/version
```

返送したいレスポンス

```
{
  'version':'ver 1.2'
}
```

### ソースコード

/(apiアプリケーション名)/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import VersionView

urlpatterns = [
    path('version', VersionView,name='version'),
]
```

/(apiアプリケーション名)/views.py

```
import json

from django.shortcuts import render

def VersionView(request, *args,**kwargs):
    params = {
        'version':
            json.dumps({'version':'ver 1.2'},indent=2)
    }
    return render(request,"api/version.html",params)
```

/(apiアプリケーション名)/templates/(apiアプリケーション名)/version.html

```
{{version}}
```

### 結果

PostManでの結果

```
GET:http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/version

[Pretty]タブ
{
  &quot;version&quot;: &quot;ver 1.2&quot;
}
[Preview]タブ
{ "version": "ver 1.2" }
```

通常、Prettyタブの結果で、インデント生成されたJSONデータが表示されるのですが、上記のようになってしまいます。

Comment: [JSONの仕様](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)としては文字列を囲むのはダブルクォーテーションらしいですね。[■文字列 (string)](https://so-zou.jp/web-app/tech/programming/javascript/json/#string), [Single vs double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4162642/9014308), [Why can I not deserialise a JSON string with single quotes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69432658/9014308) JSONではないテキストデータで返して表示する側で工夫するとか、同様にJSONデータをそのままではなく表示する側でシングルクォーテーションに変換するとか、考えてみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(質問が書かれてないので感想です)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects で

```py
return JsonResponse({'version':'ver 1.2'}, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})
```

と返すべきでしょう

Comment: ありがとうございます。意図通りのレスポンスとなりました。